# Ubuntu GUI: how to bring up desktop bottom bar and work area selection?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 VM through Hyper-V on Windows. It is GUI Ubuntu. But I do not see the work area selection.

I may not use the right term, what I mean "work area" is, at the bottom of the desktop, there is a bar; within the bar, there are, by default, 4 areas. I can pick one area and I go to a separate desktop.

Actually I do not see the bottom bar at all. I just see the side bar with some applications like browser, office, etc.

Can you point me how I can bring up the bottom bar and that work areas?

Comment: In Ubuntu V20.04, click on Activities - Top Left and the Desktops appear in a bar on the right side of the screen.  I more regularly use Ubuntu V22.04 and clicking on Activities puts the desktops on the main screen, so Ubuntu is changing.

Comment: Thanks John. So v22.04 can add desktops to the main screen? I do not see how I can do  that in v20.04.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en might be helpful, in selecting the workspace (desktop) to use. (Not displaying a selection bar though)

Comment: What 20.04 does is add to the right side. Works here.